Solving partial differential equation $ay^2\partial_x u(x,y)=\nabla^2 u(x,y)+b u(x,y)$ using Fourier Transform
I wish to solve the following differential equation:
$$py^2\partial_x u(x,y)=\nabla^2 u(x,y)-q u(x,y)$$
where $p,q \in \mathbb R$ are some constants and $u(x,y)$ is a real scalar field. My idea was to take the following Fourier Transform:
$$u^*=\mathcal F(u)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}ue^{-ikx}dx$$
after which we arrive at the following equation:
$$ipky^2u^*=(-k^2+\partial_y^2 )u^*-qu^*$$
$$\Leftrightarrow \partial_y^2u^*=u^*(ipky^2)+ u^*(q+k^2)$$
This is the parabolic cylindrical differential equation.
Wikipedia states the linearly indepnedent solutions of:
$$\frac{d^2 f}{dz^2}=\left( \frac 1 4 z^2+a\right)f$$
to be

I thought of rewriting $y=\frac{z}{\sqrt 2 e^{\frac{i\pi}{8}}p^{1/4}k^{1/4}}$ and $q+k^2=2e^{\frac{i\pi}{4}}p^{1/2}k^{1/2}a$. This would give rise to the expression given in Wikipedia. However, how would I define $k^{1/4}$? If I tried working with the principal branch, applied the boundary conditions and took the inverse Fourier Transform, would the answer be reliable? Does this procedure even make sense? Does there exist a less involved way to solve this PDE?
Also should I post this question to Mathoverflow instead?
